# Tests for Pay To Taproot addresses?

Tags: taproot, testing, p2tr, bip350-bech32m

I am having trouble finding examples showing a known WIF to a valid mainnet P2TR address.

I am working on a tool and want to see if my P2TR conversions/encodings are outputting the correct P2TR address.

For example, a known Private Key (empty string brain wallet):
`L4rK1yDtCWekvXuE6oXD9jCYfFNV2cWRpVuPLBcCU2z8TrisoyY1`

I am getting the following P2TR:
`bc1pw74tdcrxlzn5r8z6ku2vztr86fgq0m245s72mjktf4afwzsf8ugs0gs8zu`

Is this the correct P2TR for this private key. Any way I can test/confirm this is correct?

Comment: I've been working on a set of wallet-focused test vectors for BIP341: https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/pull/1225

Comment: If I use that WIF key directly as output pubkey (not recommended) I get `bc1p5d9enu3v0yxyud4jk0pvxk3kmvrzymjpc6f0eq4ck44vr32qck7scr6tj5`. If I use the procedure in BIP341 (tweaking it with H_TapTweak(xonly_pubkey))), I get `bc1ps7qmhrpjnkwrraxwparm4drmvk4jdj6rlg4gtwm0q0je3r7afhnspef95z`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meanwhile, [BIP341 has been updated to link to a set of test vectors](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0341.mediawiki#Test_vectors) covering scriptPubKey computation, keypath spending, and control block construction.